# A flat file Unit of Work (DDD) pertinence?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, unit-of-work

So, I'm working on a DDD application, I'll skip the details, but globally: one of the service aims to retrieve information from a Database, process it and write the "processed data" (an aggregate actually) into a flatfile (and no, I cannot change that - the flat file is to be sent to a printer that can interpret the file). Nothing out of the ordinary except for the flatfile part. When writing down the code, I was thinking that of course, I need to write into a file the result of the processed data as part of my application service, and to me, it is the same as writing an aggregate to database using a unit of work through a repository class.

So my question is: Is a FlatFileUnitOfWork legitimate as part of a DDD? If so, does anyone have a (good) example of it ? Because to me, it is rather uncommon, and I wasn't able to find a correct example of a "FlatFileUnitOfWork".

Thanks a lot.

NB: The Web API is written in C#

Comment: Imho no. Flat file is a data exchange format, not persistence storage, so no suitable as source of aggregates. If its meant to be print, then this happen outside your domain, as you say its a regular application service (i.e. a consequence of "place order" command/action). UnitOfWork is for presistance, your use case is more of the "export aggregate x as format y". Treat it same as you would for calling a remote service (i.e. print order service)

Comment: That's a good point to view it as a "command" event. And therefore to give a format rather than persist the data in a file. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining [TSeng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59105825/a-flat-file-unit-of-work-ddd-pertinence#comment104445341_59105825), I'd say it depends! :)

According to your description, Unit of Work is very ***unlikely*** a fitting pattern in your case. What is a proper solution, in [DDD](https://dddcommunity.org/), as its name suggests, depends on the domain! - **(EDIT: shortened)**

My question would be: what's the business process behind that printing. Is this just a minor matter - or is it a crucial part of the core domain *(e.g. the whole application is about revolutionary printing out cool designed concert tickets)* - or something between?

If it's just a minor matter - far away, kinda nothing to do with the core domain - then an application event or command might be OK. E.g. you emit an application event in your core domain's context, which is then caught in another context, who lets the printer do its job via sending that flat file to it. Alternatively, this printing might belong to the same context *(still being a minor issue)*. In that case, your application service might call *(or "command")* the porper module of the infrastructure layer doing that printing via flat file.

If it's part of the core domain then it might happen e.g. that a domain service is somehow responsible for composing that crucial printing stuff - or something like that. In this case, precise details of the solution would depend on a thorough analysis *(knowledge crunching, domain modelling)* of the core domain.

**EDIT - Sample Case**

For my sample case, I imagine you have a Ticket Printing micro-service, which is your core domain, - because you are printing the coolest concert tickets ever, and that's the main point of the whole application.

Within this service, I imagine you have a complex domain model for building up that coolest ticket layout, on top of which there's a `TicketComposer` providing a `TicketToPrint` value object containing all important information you need for that printing - e.g. like this:

```
public TicketToPrint ComposeTicketToPrint(SoldTicket ticket)
{
    // ...
}
```

In that case, you need a `TicketPrinter` class in your **Infrastructure** layer, who does the job of printing out that ticket. Neither your **Domain** nor your **Application** layer shouldn't even know how it does that. I.e. your application service method would look something like this:

```
public void PrintSoldTicket(SoldTicketDTO ticketDto)
{
    SoldTicket soldTicket = CreateSoldTicket(ticketDto);

    var composer = new TicketComposer();
    TicketToPrint ticketToPrint = composer.ComposeTicketToPrint(soldTicket);

    var printer = new TicketPrinter();
    printer.Print(ticketToPrint);
}
```

And then in the end of the chain, your `TicketPrinter` in **Infrastructure** layer does the job you are asking:

```
public void Print(TicketToPrint ticketToPrint)
{
    // Creating the flat file and sending it to the printer...
}
```

Does this sample answer your question?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand exactly what you are explaining. But, yes, the printing part is clearly part of the core domain, but the printing itself is under the responsability of another party (the printer). The responsability of the service here is to create a file with enough information for the printer to print correctly. So my question is not: Who has responsability for composing the file that the printer will interpret. But rather: How to write and save such file into a specific folder without breaking SRP, DDD principles and overall SOLID principles.

Comment: Sorry, - I'm afraid, my description has become too complicated. :(  My point is: there are several options. Which one is the right one, depends on the domain. Still, I'm trying to give you a more concrete example - in an EDIT of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, it seems more justifiable to use this kind of code without breaking the DD design. I'll think about it, but it seems like a good answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

The printer looks like a UI layer from the DDD, it just "displays" the data.

You should have some kind of Presenter which passes the Aggregate to some Infrastructure service which is responsible for translation of the Aggregate into a format which is understandable by the printer.